# WriteFile() call works on x86, but not x64. Getting error code 6 -- The handle is invalid using VB.NET

Tags: createfile, overlapped-io

I am using CreateFile, WriteFile and ReadFile API calls to write some data to a USB device. The code I have works perfectly on 32 bit systems. CreateFile gets a handle to the device, pass that handle and some data to WriteFile and read from that handle with ReadFile.

My problem is, the same code does not work on a 64 bit system. The error returned from WriteFile is 6, The handle is invalid. I've checked the handle for validity on the CreateFile call and it is a valid handle. A call to GetLastError() returns 0 after CreateFile. The "file" is being opened for overlapped communication and the overlapped init calls are also returning their proper values.

My question: is there some sort of different consideration I need to make because it's a 64 bit system? A different flag? A different call altogether?

Just to note, I did a little bit of a hack on the code to make it synchronous (took out the OVERLAPPED) and it worked, so I'm assuming the problem is in my OVERLAPPED structure or the way I'm initializing the calls.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Below are my API signatures and the code I am using for my OVERLAPPED implementation

```
Private Declare Auto Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32.dll" _
                                    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
                                    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, _
                                    ByVal dwShareMode As Integer, _
                                    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, _
                                    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Integer, _
                                    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Integer, _
                                    ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As IntPtr


Private Declare Auto Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32.dll" _
                                    (ByVal hFile As IntPtr, ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
                                    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Integer, _
                                    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer, _
                                    ByRef lpOverlapped As OVERLAPPED) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32.dll" _
                                    (ByVal hFile As IntPtr, _
                                    ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
                                    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Integer, _
                                    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer, _
                                    ByRef lpOverlapped As OVERLAPPED) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hFile As IntPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function CancelIo Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function GetOverlappedResult Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
                                    ByVal hFile As IntPtr, ByRef lpOverlapped As OVERLAPPED, _
                                    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesTransferred As Integer, _
                                    ByVal bWait As Boolean) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function CreateEvent Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
                                    ByVal lpEventAttributes As Integer, ByVal bManualReset As Boolean, _
                                    ByVal bInitialState As Boolean, _
                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpName As String) As IntPtr

Private Declare Auto Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
                                    ByVal hHandle As IntPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Integer) As Integer
```

The following is the code for the write, where the issue occurs. It should be noted that in the read, the OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent parameter is initialized in the same fashion

```
Try

        With IOStructure
            .overlap.hEvent = CreateEvent(Nothing, True, False, Nothing)
            If .overlap.hEvent = 0 Then
                writeSuccess = False
            Else
                writeSuccess = WriteFile(.hdevice, .writeBuf, .writeBuf.Length, .bytesWritten, .overlap)

                'If the write didn't succeed, check to see if it's pending
                If Not writeSuccess Then

                    If Err.LastDllError <> ERROR_IO_PENDING Then 'The write failed
                        writeSuccess = False
                    Else ' Write is pending

                        Select Case WaitForSingleObject(.overlap.hEvent, .timeout * 0.1) 'Wait for the write to complete

                            Case 0 'The write completed, check the overlapped structure for the signalled event.
                                writeSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(.hdevice, .overlap, .bytesWritten, 0)
                            Case Else
                                writeSuccess = False
                        End Select
                    End If

                End If
            End If
            CloseHandle(.overlap.hEvent)
        End With
        '   Thread.Sleep(IOStructure.timeout * 0.3)
        ' End While
    Catch
        writeSuccess = False
    End Try
```

Comment: I just edited my post with the relevant code.

Comment: Don't use Boolean for BOOL type. Int32 BOOL is 32-bit value, use int or Int32. For all functions with string parameters, explicitly define MarshalAs and use A or W postfix accordingly - just for safety. Show PInvoke definition of OVERLAPPED structure.

Comment: I will make that change and let you know how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... I found that the invalid handle error disappeared when I explicitly zeroed the overlapped structure:

```
Dim ovl As OVERLAPPED
static ovlRead As IntPtr = Nothing

' Marshal (allocate unmanaged) structure only once
If IsNothing(ovlRead) then
    ovlRead = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ovl))

    Marshal.WriteInt32(ovlRead, 0, 0)
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ovlRead, 4, 0)
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ovlRead, 8, 0)
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ovlRead, 12, 0)
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ovlRead, 16, 0)
End If
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Same symptoms. I fixed it by

1. At program start-up when I first open the port I purge the I/O buffers
2. I then write a 0x00 (null) character to the port itself using WriteFile to initialize it.

And BINGO it works. Haven't had problems since.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [NativeOverlapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.nativeoverlapped.aspx)? It's specifically designed for this task.